# 2 Separate Clusters Weblogic Foreing JNDI Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, weblogic

I'm developing two separate applications using just JEE technologies, with Weblogic as application server.

The first one **App-Client** which is a web-application with jsp and other stuff, the second one **App-business** is an application that expose several EJB (stateless session bean Facades) which integrates with JMS resources,webservices, and datasources. Each application is deployed in a weblogic cluster with two nodes (**Cluster1** and **Cluster2**) on different machines under the same domain. Is it possible to connect both JNDI trees using Foreign JNDI configuration of the Weblogic App server? If its possible, The remote Ip's that i will have to configure in **Cluster1** are the ones of each node of **cluster2**, or If i use the master node Ip (Domain administrator) I will be able to use the internal Weblogic JNDI Three load balancing capacities, when **App-client** invoke EJBs in **App-business**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a JMS module in cluster1 and point it to cluster2. That way, you can reference the JNDI entries in cluster2 on cluster1. Detailed steps are described here -> http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4739
This configuration is called "Messaging Bridge"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but my doubt is not with JMS rather than with the whole JNDI tree, I know that with the Extternal Foreign JNDI configuratión i can access from one cluster the second cluster JNDI tree but i'm not sure who will be doing the load balancing between the EJB's. If i configure the external jndi provider urls as is specified on the documentation i have to provide the ips of all the nodes, so I think the "client cluster" will do the load balancing, but I think that if i only put the ip of the master node (domain), this node will do the load balancing